# How to pass Obfuscated Elf binary to gcc optimization end

Tags: assembly, c, deobfuscation, gcc

Currently I have a 2000+Line function to reverse engineer with many redundancies and appears to be  obfuscated. It their a way to pass to pass this binary to gcc or clang to reassemble it and optimize it ?

Comment: Have you tried passing it to Hex-Rays to see the decompiled results?

Comment: assuming that I dont have access to hexray or any other paid software ( I really dont)

Comment: "reassembling" is just a tough concept, perhaps you might want to look for a decompiler or maybe you just want to upload your DLL for someone to show you the decompiled code of the function.

Comment: You can try to use http://retdec.com as a decompiler.

Comment: I appreciate this but what I really want to know how to achieve it to disassemble then re assemble a bin file and pass it to gcc -o3